# Get a list of endpoints called by the frontend and on which webpage they are called

Tags: frontend, backend, endpoint

I want to refactor some back-end code. This code communicates with a front-end app, where the front-end app calls a bunch of APIs. I wish to trim the responses provided by the back-end. For this purpose, I want to know what properties does the front-end actually require. So, I want to know where an API endpoint is called on the front-end. Is there any tool which can solve this problem? A tool, to which I give the input my front-end application, it outputs me on what webpage it is calling a particular endpoint. Please note that this is the reverse of doing `Ctrl+Shift+I`, where I would want to know what endpoint is being called on a particular webpage. What this question is asking instead is, that I do not know the webpage which calls a particular endpoint, can you tell me how to find the webpage, given that I know everything about the API endpoint?

Comment: Monitor network requests in chrome’s developer pane, disable clearing of requests on page changes and visit all your web pages. You can then inspect every call made and from which page.

Comment: @YassineElBouchaibi Thanks for the comment. This seems like a brute force method. Is there an easier way to visit all pages automatically or with a tool? Furthermore, I will also need to fill forms on pages etc, to trigger all api calls. Is there an automated way to this also?